# Show slides depending on checked radio button

Tags: javascript

I have a slider with 6 slides in it. My goal is to show only 3 first slides if radio button id="male" is checked and 3 last slides if id="female" button is currently checked. I've tried splicing array in half and setting slide index depending on checked button but it didn't help. Here is my HTML code:

```js
   function skinSlider() {
        let slideIndex = 1,
          female = document.getElementById('female'),
          male = document.getElementById('male'),
          skinSlider = document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0],
          skinSliderItem = document.getElementsByClassName('skin-color'),
          prev = skinSlider.querySelector('.prev'),
          next = skinSlider.querySelector('.next');

        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
          plusSlides(-1);
        });

        next.addEventListener('click', () => {
          plusSlides(1);
        });

        function showSlides(n) {
          // if (female.checked && slideIndex < 4) {
          //   slideIndex = 4;
          // }
          if (n > skinSliderItem.length) {
            slideIndex = 1;
          }
          if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = skinSliderItem.length;
          }

          for (let i = 0; i < skinSliderItem.length; i++) {
            skinSliderItem[i].style.display = 'none';
          }

          skinSliderItem[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';

          let personSkin = document.getElementById('person-skin');
          personSkin.style.background = `url('./img/skin/skin-${slideIndex}.png') center no-repeat`;
          personSkin.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
        }
      };
```

```html
<div class="radio">
      <input value="male" id="male" name="sex" type="radio">
      <label for="sex">Male</label>
      <input value="female" id="female" checked name="sex" type="radio">
      <label for="sex">Female</label>
     </div>
     <div class="custom-style">
 <div class="style-text">
  Choose skin color
 </div>
 <div class="skin">
 <div class="prev">
  <i class="flaticon-left-arrow"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-1"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-2"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-3"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-4"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-5"></div>
 <div class="skin-color skin-color-6"></div>
 <div class="next">
  <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
 </div>
      </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in the `HTML` part, what are th elements that define the slides to show if male has been checked and those for female ?

Comment: There are 2 inputs with id "male" and "female", if "female" input is checked only 3 last items in slider should be available and vice versa for "male".

Comment: What ``HTML` element is the slider ?!

Comment: Div with class skin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this accomplishes roughly what you're looking for. Unfortunately, the slider "wraps" when moving to the right and simply stops at the lower limit when moving to the left. But I'll leave that as an additional challenge for you.  :-)

```js
  function skinSlider() {
    let slideIndex = 1,
      female = document.getElementById('female'),
      male = document.getElementById('male'),
      skinSlider = document.getElementsByClassName('skin')[0],
      skinSliderItem = document.getElementsByClassName('skin-color'),
      prev = skinSlider.querySelector('.prev'),
      next = skinSlider.querySelector('.next');

    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
      plusSlides(-1);
    });

    next.addEventListener('click', () => {
      plusSlides(1);
    });
    
    female.addEventListener('click', () => {
      showSlides(slideIndex);
    });
    
    male.addEventListener('click', () => {
      showSlides(slideIndex);
    });

    function showSlides(n) {
      if (slideIndex > skinSliderItem.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      
      if (slideIndex < 1) {
        slideIndex = skinSliderItem.length;
      }
      
      if (female.checked && slideIndex < 4) {
        slideIndex = 4;
      } else if (male.checked && slideIndex > 3) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < skinSliderItem.length; i++) {
        skinSliderItem[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      
      skinSliderItem[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
    }
  };
  
  skinSlider();
```

```html
 <div class="radio">
  <input value="male" id="male" name="sex" type="radio">
  <label for="sex">Male</label>
  <input value="female" id="female" checked name="sex" type="radio">
  <label for="sex">Female</label>
 </div>
 <div class="custom-style">
<div class="style-text">
 Choose skin color
</div>
<div class="skin">
<div class="prev">
 &lt;
</div>
<div class="skin-color skin-color-1">1</div>
<div class="skin-color skin-color-2">2</div>
<div class="skin-color skin-color-3">3</div>
<div class="skin-color skin-color-4">4</div>
<div class="skin-color skin-color-5">5</div>
<div class="skin-color skin-color-6">6</div>
<div class="next">
 &gt;
</div>
  </div>
```

As an aside, the `for` attribute of the label elements should use the IDs of the associated inputs, not the name of the checkbox group.